# Adding hyperlink to Word doc using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, hyperlink

I am creating a Word document through an Excel VBA Add-In and would like to change certain phrases in the Word document into a hyperlink. I do not get an error, but my code does not work.

```vb
    Dim linkText    As String: linkText = "https://cdphe.colorado.gov/drinking-water-water-hauler-rule"
    Dim link        As String: link = "https://cdphe.colorado.gov/drinking-water-water-hauler-rule"

    With appWD.ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Execute FindText:="http://www.colorado.gov/cdphe/hauler"
        With appWD.Selection
          .EndKey 6, 0
          .TypeParagraph
          .TypeText "text without link"
          .TypeParagraph
          .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range, Address:=link, SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=linkText
        End With
    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Const linkText As String = "https://cdphe.colorado.gov/drinking-water-water-hauler-rule"
    Const link As String = "https://cdphe.colorado.gov/drinking-water-water-hauler-rule"
    
    Dim rng As Range, appWD As Object

    'set appWD to Word instance...
    
    Set rng = appWD.ActiveDocument.Content 'range to be searched
    If rng.Find.Execute(FindText:="http://www.colorado.gov/cdphe/hauler") Then
        rng.Select ' `rng` is now the found text: select it
        With appWD.Selection
          .EndKey 6, 0
          .TypeParagraph
          .TypeText "text without link"
          .TypeParagraph
          .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range, Address:=link, _
                SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=linkText
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Probably better to work directly with `rng` once the `Find` succeeds though.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I think I need to clarify, I am using an Excel VBA Add-In to generate the Word document using a Word template. All of the VBA code is in the Excel Add-In VBA. Is there a method to add the hyperlink in a Word document using Excel VBA?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the code I posted was from Word - you'll need to make the adjustments for running that in Excel VBA.  I will edit...

Comment: Much appreciated, Tim.

Comment: I switched gears as I could not get the Excel to run and add hyperlinks to a Word document. I was able to call a Word macro stored in a .dotm template and can run from there. I will have another thread with another question regarding that macro. thank you so very much for the assistance.